# How to compile node-sass in current dir for individual files

Tags: css, npm, sass, node-sass

I have a structure like so:

```
- folder1
  - styles1.scss

- folder2
  - styles2.scss
```

I need to run `node-sass` **from the command line** to produce the following:

```
- folder1
  - styles1.scss
  - styles1.css

- folder2
  - styles2.scss
  - styles2.css
```

These folder will be a lot eventually.
So I'd like all the individual files to compile to CSS next to their `.scss` file.

Currently I have:

```
"sass:build": "node-sass src/app/**/*.scss -o src/app/"
```

But this just puts stuff directly into `src/app`, regardless the depth of the folder inside `src/app`
How would I do this?

Comment: Did you try `-o src/app/**/*` ?

Comment: Yes I tried, but then it seems to override the first file it encounters with the same name without the extension, so `home.scss` next to `home.html` will cause `node-sass` to override `home.html` with the compiled CSS.

Comment: then try to just do this `node-sass src/app -o src/app`

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @cyrix pointed out in the comments, I can achieve my goal using:

```
node-sass src/app -o src/app
```

Comment: What if the files are in the same folder as the script? `node-sass ./ -o ./` seems not to work. It gives an error: Unsupported source map encoding charset=utf8;base64

Comment: This works, but I was wondering how can I watch these files and update changes as I save changes. -w did not seem to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Above answer by @Nicky works well. However, in order to watch the folders (so that the script outputs css files on each save, apply the following code:

```bash
"node-sass  -rw src/scss -o dist/scss/ --output-style compressed"
```

the -rw option watches for changes recursively in the src/scss folder, and outputs the files in dist/scss.
The --output-style compressed is optional.

You can also use this script in package.json file.

```json
 "scripts": {
    "compile" : "node-sass  -rw src/scss -o dist/scss/ --output-style compressed"
  }
```

so that we can run `npm run compile` for the changes.

I added this answer because adding `-w` to the solution did not work, which works well for when watching a single file , e.g:

```bash
node-sass src/scss/styles.scss src/css/style.css -w --output-style compressed
```

But not for when watching the whole directory, as shown above. Hope this is helpful.